# How do people make the fancy titles displayed when bash script its run

Tags: bash, title

How can I make bash script have a cool title

Currently I am just using echo to give the name arg cliccker to my script

instead of having one boring line
how do i make fnacy bash sript logos

like this below:

[image: just like the logo at tope of this shell]

Comment: Check out [figlet](http://www.figlet.org).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `tput` commands. `tput` is used to alter the terminal characteristics.

e.g

```
tput bold
tput setaf 3
tput setab 4
tput reset
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some website that can do it.
Check out this website:
http://www.kammerl.de/ascii/AsciiSignature.php

Answer (score 1):

Try installing 'boxes' - From the man page:

> DESCRIPTION Boxes  is  a  text  filter  which can draw any kind of box
>   around its input text. Box design choices range from simple boxes to
>   complex ASCII art. A box can also be removed and repaired, even if it
>   has been badly damaged by editing of the text inside. Since boxes may
>   be open on any  side,  boxes  can  also  be  used  to  create regional
>   comments in any programming language.  New box designs of all sorts
>   can easily be added and shared by appending to a free format
>   configuration file. boxes  was originally intended to be used with the
>   vim(1) text editor, but it can be tied to any text editor which
>   supports filters, as well as called from the command line as a
>   standalone tool.

```
$ boxes -h
boxes - draws any kind of box around your text (and removes it)
        (c) Thomas Jensen <boxes@thomasjensen.com>
        Web page: http://boxes.thomasjensen.com/
Usage:  boxes [options] [infile [outfile]]
        -a fmt   alignment/positioning of text inside box [default: hlvt]
        -c str   use single shape box design where str is the W shape
        -d name  box design [default: first one in file]
        -f file  configuration file
        -h       print usage information
        -i mode  indentation mode [default: box]
        -k bool  leading/trailing blank line retention on removal
        -l       list available box designs w/ samples
        -m       mend box, i.e. remove it and redraw it afterwards
        -p fmt   padding [default: none]
        -r       remove box
        -s wxh   box size (width w and/or height h)
        -t str   tab stop distance and expansion [default: 8e]
        -v       print version information
```

:)
Dale

Answer (score 1):

I prefer 3 tools:

- `figlet` - makes big fancy letters (like on your screenshot)
- `lolcat` - makes colorful and animated title
- `boxes`  - makes fancy border for your title

Usage:

```bash
   figlet "Your fancy title" | lolcat -a -s 100 
   figlet "Your fancy title" | lolcat -a -s 100 | boxes -d nuke
```

Example from `boxes` official site:

[image]